# Autosar Rte_Receive event with wait state and activation of task

Tags: events, operating-system, wait, autosar

I am starting to learn about writing application in AUTOSAR and I have run into this question to which I am not able to find a concrete solution. If you could provide an answer based on your experience/knowledge it would be very helpful.

I have a periodic task of 100ms and I want to have a RTE_Receive with wait state in this task. That means as soon as the respective event occurs, my task gets into active-ready state.

Does that mean the task starts running in the same cycle(when the event occurs) or does it wait for the next 100ms cycle to run the task? I just want to determine the worst case latency. If implementing Receive-wait is better than just RTE_read(which just process the data in the next avaialable cycle)

Sorry if the question sounds too dumb. I'm just trying to learn the AUTOSAR concepts.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is some misunderstanding.

According to your example scenario, The task is periodically activated and starts running even before the `Rte_Receive()` API is executed, blocking or not. After all, the API call to `Rte_Receive()` is executed in the code of a `RunnableEntity` executed as part of the task body.

Again, the event that starts the task is the expiration of the respective timer, not the reception of data.

Comment: As I read my question again, I undestand I didn't put it very clearly. I know it is activated periodically.
I mean, what if the task is in wait state? and the receive-event occurs, does the task resume immediately or does it wait for next periodic execution from the OS?